# How do i get createAccount methods argument in after plugin Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, after-plugin

I am writing after plugin on create account method, to change the API response with.
I have to call

> `createCustomerAccessToken($username, $password)`

function, which has two parameters. What I am doing is i take the username from `createAccount` method and pass it to `createCustomerAccessToken` function.I can easily get the `$username` value how i can get the password parameter value?

```
<?php

namespace Mlameh\Store\Plugin;

class AddAccessToken
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionFactory
 */
private $customerExtensionFactory;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\TokenFactory
 */
private $tokenModelFactory;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Integration\Model\CustomerTokenService
 */
private $customerTokenService;
private $token;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Integration\Model\CustomerTokenService $customerTokenService
) {
    $this->customerTokenService = $customerTokenService;
}

/**
 * Add Login token to customer
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $subject ,
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer
 * @return  \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException
 */
public function afterCreateAccount(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $subject,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer
) {
    
    //$password = 
    $token['token'] = $this->customerTokenService->createCustomerAccessToken(
        $customer->getEmail()
    );
    return $customer;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the arguments of the observed method in your after plugin as well. As I can see you are observing following method which has three arguments

> `\Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement:createAccount(CustomerInterface $customer, $password = null, $redirectUrl = '')`

You can simply use all the needed arguments of observed methods in your plugin as

```
public function afterCreateAccount(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $subject,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $result,
    $customer,
    $password = null
) {
   /* Your code */
}
```

For more clarification refer https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Hope it was helpful.
Thanks

Comment: If i pass the $password =null, then it will passed same null value to  createCustomerAccessToken method.right?

Comment: I need the password value which user enter in Login API parameter.